# Selenium+Selenide. Тест падает когда элемент имеет свойство displayed:false

Tags: selenium

Есть элемент  `<label class="CI-MultiplePickerList-column-name-img_logout CI-MultiplePickerList-LAB" style="display: inline;"/>` 
с CSS локатором

```
.CI-MultiplePickerList-column-name-img_logout.CI-MultiplePickerList-LAB
```

Этот элемент может иметь два статуса - когда виден пользователю и когда не виден.

**Проблема:**
После нажатия по этому элементу, когда он имеет статус displayed:false (т.е. когда не виден пользователю), тест падает и появляется ошибка:

```
Element should be visible {.CI-MultiplePickerList-column-name-img_logout.CI-MultiplePickerList-LAB}
Element: '<label class="CI-MultiplePickerList-column-name-img_logout CI-MultiplePickerList-LAB" displayed:false></label>'
```

Я пытался отловить ошибку через exception:

```
try {
        $(By.cssSelector(".CI-MultiplePickerList-column-name-img_logout.CI-MultiplePickerList-LAB")).click();
    }
    catch (ElementNotFound e){
        System.out.print("Not logged in profile");
    }
```

но это не помогло.

Как можно решить эту проблему так, чтобы тест не падал при нажатии на элемент со свойством displayed:false?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась через метод getAttrubite и использованием оператора if. Я проверяю какое значение имеет интересующий атрибут и если он невидимый (имеет статус display: none), то игнорирую его.

```
if($(By.cssSelector(".CI-MultiplePickerList-column-name-img_logout.CI-MultiplePickerList-LAB")).getAttribute("style").equals("display: none;")) {
            System.out.print("Ignored");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Else, click it");
            $(By.cssSelector(".CI-MultiplePickerList-column-name-img_logout.CI-MultiplePickerList-LAB")).click();
    }
```